# Store repeating sequence of integer in another array

Tags: java, arrays, search, integer, sequence

I have two arrays a[] and b[].

```
int a[]={3,1,1,1,7,4,6,6,3,1};
int b[]=new int[a.length];
```

Array length in actual problem can change.
The values in the array must be less then value of array length as seen.

---

The output must be:

```
b = 3 1 0 0 7 4 6 0 3 1
```

So basically if there is a sequence of same value in a[] then only 1st of its value must be placed at same index in b[] rest should be zero till the sequence exists.

---

Answer in java syntax will be helpful.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us some effort and we'll be happy to help.  What we won't do is write your homework for you.

Comment: Agreed. But as a hint, take these three steps. Firstly, do the problem yourself. Next, figure out _how_ you did it. Finally, code that. In other words, put aside Java, programming, all that -- and just figure out how you, a human, would do it. Chance as you'll use some sort of logical set of steps. Now just write those steps down in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int a[]={3,1,1,1,7,4,6,6,3,1};
    int b[]=new int[a.length];

    int temp = a[0];
    b[0] = temp;

    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) { 
        if(a[i] == temp)
            b[i] = 0;
        else
            b[i] = a[i];

        temp = a[i];    
    }
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because this isn't "obviously wrong" as per the FAQ, but please don't encourage these sorts of questions by answering them.

Comment: Can you show up to take his tests for him too?

Answer (score 0):

hint:

1) create hashmap to store processed values

2) iterate over the first array: if current value is stored in map, then fill 0, otherwise store this value in HashMap and copy the value to new array

Comment: This won't work. He only wants sequences of the same value zeroed out. This will remove every instance of a number after the first.

Comment: you are right, I should read it better. Then he just needs to remember previous value.